# fopen error in PHP

Tags: php, image, file-writing

I seem to be having some issues with my code, particularly with the `fopen()` command.

Is this the correct way to write images to a file? Would I also need to include `r` if I want to read from that image file later?

Here is what i have.

```
$boiler_img = $_FILES['boiler_image']; 
$dir = "images/boilers/";

$myfile = fopen("images/Boilers/"".$boiler_img.", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $boiler_img);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried it out but the file wasn't in the directory. Am I executing the command correctly? `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["boiler_image"]["tmp_name"], $dir.$_FILES["boiler_image"]["name"]);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just handling a simple file upload. You can just use the tmp_name, name and the move_uploaded_file function to move it for you.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"], $dir.$_FILES["pictures"]["name"];
```